# Rails - Render html with an ajax request in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I would like render format.html if param[:date] != nil and render .js if it's not nil.

My link_to :

```
<%= link_to place_path(place, date: params[:date]), id: "#{place.id}", remote: true, authenticity_token: true, data: { title: place.city }, target: "_blank" do %>
```

My controller :

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController    
  def show
    if params[:date] == nil
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          preparation_of_instance_variables_for_show_view
        }
        format.js { }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          preparation_of_instance_variables_for_show_view
        }
        format.js {
          render format: 'html' # <= where I want to render format.html
        }
      end
      go_to_show_view
    end


  end

  private

  def preparation_of_instance_variables_for_show_view
    @place = Place.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if params[:date].present?
      @guests = Booking.accepted.where(place: @place, date: Date.parse(params[:date])).map(&:guest)
    end
  end
```

How I can to redirect to the format.html just for this case?

Comment: I have show.js.erb and I render it when I am in the first case but I want to render show.html.erb for the second case of js request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in your question that you want to render html if its != (not equal) to nil and to render js if it's not equal to nil. You can't render both on the same condition! Either way you should wrap the respond_to around the if condition:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    if params[:date] # This means if params[:date] has a value (true)          
      format.html {
        preparation_of_instance_variables_for_show_view
      }
    else # If params[:date] is equal to nil 
      format.js {}
    end # End of if params[:date]
      go_to_show_view
  end # End of respond_to
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear.
Your solution does not render me the HTML. On the other hand, if I remove "remote: true" to the link_to in the inspector, the controller render me show.html.erb

Comment: Yes, that's because 'remote: true' is telling rails that the request is via AJAX and it is expecting a .js response. Maybe you could set the if statement around where your <%= link_to %> is so that if there is a date then no 'remote: true' (& html is rendered), else if there's no date then set 'remote: true' (& js is rendered).

Comment: Yes of course. That is the solution I was thinking of. But I thought it was not very clean.
Thanks in any case;)